# RN callkeep: error cannot find symbol with FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm building a react-native application and I want to add the [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) package in my project. However, I didn't succeed in running the project with this package. I firstly thought the callkeep package was interfering with the packages that I already used in the project so I started a new react-native project only with the callkeep package to see if it worked. Unfortunately, I have the same error. [Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq43h.png).

Here is what I made to start and run the test project:

1. `npx react-native init <my project name>`
2. `npm install react-native-callkeep`
3. `npx react-native link react-native-callkeep`
4. I followed the instructions for Android described [here](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/blob/master/docs/android-installation.md)
5. `npx react-native run-android`

I didn't find any solution in the github of react-native-callkeep and on the Internet so I'm turning to you in hope that someone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I found my error. It seems I can't run the app with `npx react-native run-android` on its own. Here is the commands to write to make the app functional:

1. `npx react-native start` in a terminal to run the metro bundler
2. `npx react-native run-android` in another terminal to run the app through the metro bundler ran in point 1.